# Is there a way to directly construct controlled gates in continuous variable (CV) quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-gate, continuous-variable

We know that a universal gate set for CV quantum computation is that of squeezing, beam splitters, and some nonlinear gate (e.g. [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1530/15820)). We also know from Knill, Laflamme, and Milburn that linear optics plus some postselection is enough to universally do CV quantum computation (e.g. [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2550/15820)). Is there a direct way to implement an arbitrary controlled operation in CV quantum computation? More specifically, can this be done using only Gaussian states and, perhaps, postselection (which, I guess, makes states non-Gaussian)?

The controlled gates I am envisioning are controlled Gaussian operations such as displacements that depend on whether or not a control mode is vacuum or nonvaccum. An operator of the form
$$cD\sim|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes \hat{D}(\beta_1)+ |\alpha\rangle\langle \alpha|\otimes \hat{D}(\beta_2)$$ would be ideal, where I realize there will be problems with the overlap $\langle \alpha|0\rangle$.

Is this type of thing directly possible, or do we have to convert between a whole bunch of things to make progress (eg create TMSV, post select on a single photon in one mode, use the single photon to control some phase shift, then use the phase shift to do some Gaussian operation)?

Even a gate like
$$cD\sim|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes \hat{D}(\beta_1)+ |1\rangle\langle 1|\otimes \hat{D}(\beta_2)$$ would be helpful - I could see this being easier.