# What is the explicit action of the non-linear gate in CV quantum computing on the quadratures?

Tags: quantum-gate, universal-gates, continuous-variable

In this excellently answered question '[How are gates implemented in a continuous-variable quantum computer?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/how-are-gates-implemented-in-a-continuous-variable-quantum-computer?newreg=8373ab721dcd4120a9b2ee9c578ae700)' the typical gates for CV quantum computing were listed and described. In particular for almost all the gates there is a description of their resulting effects on the quadrature position ($X$) and momentum ($P$).

The exception is with the action of the Kerr hamiltonian (whose action is also not described explicitely on the quadratures in the original paper by Lloyd either). There is likely a reason for this but all the same my question is:

What is the action of the Kerr hamiltonian, or a non linear equivalent like the cubic gate, on the quadratures (in the sense that the translation with P sends $x$ to $x+t$ or the squeeze gate $x$ to $xe^t$ etc)?

Comment: Why not work it out yourself? If you understood the answer to the question you provided the link to, you should be perfectly able to compute the actions. Hint: for the Kerr Hamiltonian you should find an infinite series, for the cubic Hamiltonian $H=X^3/3$, you can find a nice closed form.